# How can I paste Excel and MS Word table and edit it on website in Angular

Tags: html, excel, angular, tabular

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

> A user can copy table from Excel/MS-Word and then paste it to my
>   angular website which he/she can then save it to server as well.

How Can I achieve this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this problem related to angular

Comment: Do you want to save the table as html?

Comment: @NabilShahid, I have liberty to save it in any form keeping in mind that user can ask to edit it latter

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor

Comment: You can copy and paste word or excel tables in it and it converts them to html table

Comment: Thanks @NabilShahid , looks like it can be helpful. Yeah I have just tested it and I can paste excel table into that. but let me test more to check if I can hide those controls on top and get the data in correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [ngx-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor) because its very easy to implement and its UI is better

install via npm

```
npm install ngx-editor --save
```

Import `ngx-editor` module

```
import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [ NgxEditorModule ]
})
```

Then in html

```
<app-ngx-editor [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [spellcheck]="true" [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"></app-ngx-editor>
```

by default its height is not set correctly but you can set min-height like this `minHeight="250px"`

> If you are getting error make sure you have imported `FormsModule`  as module
>
> Make sure `HttpClientModule` is also installed and imported

Comment: I have just tried this @ https://ngx-editor.stackblitz.io/ and it does ***not*** support copy-pasting a table from Excel.